# Permutation and Combination of a given numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
I want to count the number of combinations we can prouduce of a given number.
```

For Example M= No. of digits and N=4 Length of a number

```
M= 3 ({3,7,5}) and N=4
Possible combinations:(The given 3 numbers must be there in the combination)
3577, 3557, 7353 and 5735 and other (32  possible combination)
```

I found this code on the net. This code is giving me correct output but I can't understand what logic it is using.

Please explain the code below and what its time complexity is.

Thanks in advance.

```
#define LL long long int
#define sd(x) scanf("%d", &x)
#define MOD 1000000007
#define D double
#define LD long double

#define N 200

LL dp[N][N];

inline void solve(){
    int n, m, i, j;
    sd(m); sd(n);
    memset(dp, 0, sizeof dp);
    dp[1][1] = m;
    for(i = 1; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 1; j <= i && j <= m; j++){
            (dp[i + 1][j] += j * dp[i][j]) %= MOD;
            (dp[i + 1][j + 1] += (m - j) * dp[i][j]) %= MOD;
        }
    }
    cout<<dp[n][m]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: @user1990169 it should be 36 ( (4! x 3)/2! )

Comment: Ok, so aren't you allowing a number like 3333? Do all the digits need to be present in the number atleast once? A clarification is necessary IMO.

Comment: yes!!The given 3 numbers must be used in the combinations

Comment: Don't use macros. They only make your code harder to read. The code is also not valid C++ and has code that is unused in the example.

Comment: I guess you got code from Topcoder or Codeforces. People there use macros a lot for fast programming.

Comment: @user4084025 *The given 3 numbers must be used...* I think you should add that to your question, and you can do that now. Also, note that `N` has to be more than or equal to `M` in order to have at least one combination in your hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dp` in the code represent `dynamic programming`. In many programming contest platforms it stands from `state`.

Here in the problem:

**`dp[i][j]` represents the number of ways to use `j` different digits in `M` to form a number whose length is `i`. Some requirements: `j <= i` and `j <= M`.**

So let's assume, we already know a `dp[i][j]`.

Then we can simply calculate `dp[i + 1][j] = j * dp[i][j]` (one more slot).

As for `dp[i + 1][j + 1]`, it means we have **one more slot** and **M - j** choices can be fit in the slot. So `dp[i + 1][j + 1] = (M - j) * dp[i][j]`.

Why `M - j`? Recall that

> `j` **different** digits in `M`

Finally, with these two transition formulas and `dp[1][1]`, we can calculate any `dp[i][j]` where `i <= N` and `j <= M and j <= i`.

**Update: example**

`N = 4`, `M = 3`.

We start by calculating `dp[1][1]`, which is apparently `dp[1][1] = 3`. There is only one slot and we have `M` choices. (recall definition of `dp`)

Then we enter the loop: start from `dp[1][1]`:

To calculate `dp[1 + 1][1]`: It means we have two slot and one digits. We have only 1 choice here - use the same digit again. So `dp[1 + 1][1] = 1 * dp[1][1] = 3`. In your example, `dp[2][1]` represents `{3, 3} {5, 5} {7, 7}`;

To calculate `dp[1 + 1][1 + 1]`: it means we have two slots and two **different** digits, so we have `M - 1` choices. So it equals to `dp[2][2] = 2 * dp[1][1] = 6`. In your example, `dp[2][2] represents` `{3, 5}, {3, 7}, {5, 3}, {5, 7}, {7, 3}, {7, 5}`.

Then just follow the loop, we will get to `dp[4][3]` and it's the answer.

Comment: would you add an example ?

Comment: Thus doesn't explain what the `MOD` is for or what the runtime complexity is, which was part of the original question.

Comment: `dp[i + 1][j] += j * dp[i][j]` why `+` is used what is had to do with previous value as it shold me zero

Comment: @user4084025 Because `dp[i][j]` could be updated by `dp[i - 1][j]` and `dp[i - 1][j - 1]`.

Comment: @b4hand I think the `MOD` is just a requirement from the original question, because apparently when `N` and `M` get big the answer will be pretty large (larger than `2^32`). And the time-complexity is between `O(N * M)` and O(N * N).